# Getting mikmod to work on 64 bit fedora 17

Tags: fedora, pulse-audio

Does anyone know how to get mikmod to output audio on a 64bit Fedora 17 install?

My system is currently using pulse audio to do output(I think, the entire audio thing on Linux is rather confusing).

Mikmod is installed, but it seems like it can only output to an oss og esd device, and I can't find any way to bridge that to pulse audio.

It worked in Fedora 16, but I can't remember exactly how. Might just have had an oss->pulse thing.

Answer (score 0):

Newer mind, I found the solution. The solution is to install the *esound* packages, and then reboot the computer. The esd is apparently called esound.